# How remove white space between table rows in swift

Tags: ios, swift, rows, space

I'm trying to remove blank rows from the table.
When a row it is blank, for example, without text, the line has no contents, but creates a space. I would like to eliminate this space?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArrayDetailTableViewCell

    //configure cell

switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = "1."
        cell.valueLabel.text = array.item1
    case 1:
        if array.item2 != "cod" {
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "2."
            cell.valueLabel.text = array.item2
        } else {
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
    default:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
        cell.valueLabel.text = ""
    }
```

}

[see here the print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mvjZ.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand your question - can you explain more about your problem?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, the code you posted it not relevant to what i think your question is and what is `array.item2` have you considered using subscripts e.g. `array[2]`. Finally try this: `tableView.separatorStyle = .None`

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed a few things. Take a look now, i updated the code and let a picture of the problem. When the case does not meet the case 1 :, it leaves blank the table row. I wanted to delete this blank row or something like that

Comment: @Ewerson There is no blank space. When the case does not meet case 1 it goes in *default* case and it makes the label text value blank i.e. "".

Comment: @shripad20 look here http://i.stack.imgur.com/5mvjZ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe instead of removing that row you should prevent that row from being created. use `numberOfRowsInSection` to count the items in your array.

however I think if you just want to hide the cell, you can try using `cell.hidden` in your code:

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "1."
    cell.valueLabel.text = array.item1
case 1:
    if array.item2 != "cod" {
        cell.fieldLabel.text = "2."
        cell.valueLabel.text = array.item2
    } else {
        cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
        cell.valueLabel.text = ""
        cell.hidden = true
default:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
    cell.valueLabel.text = ""
}
}
```

Comment: ow yes thank you @apikurious ...it disappears. But the space continues between row 1 e row 2

Comment: @Ewerson I'm not too sure what you mean by the space continues between row 1 and 2? is your table a dynamic table with its data loaded from an array or something?

Comment: @apikuriuos The table bears a date core data list.
If there in the core data, for example, array.item2 != "Cod", it will display a line with the content, otherwise displays the empty line.

The problem is when it presents an empty line, I even hiding (as you suggested), it is that size of the blank line, as if content yet.

the table is disordered, as in the picture attached in trouble above.

Comment: @Ewerson then when you detect that the line is empty, hide the cell. if there is still space maybe you have an empty footer or header or something

Comment: thanks @apikurious for helping, footer has given right.
In the header can not use tableView.tableFooterView code = UIView (frame: CGRectZero) because it erases the UIImage that has above. is there any way to get the size just a particular cell to zero? (e.g heightForRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: @Ewerson yeah you can take a look at Ghulam Ali's answer. that's using height for row at index path.

Comment: I tried, but the code create an infinite loop and breaks
I showed him the problem, but did not answer.

Comment: @Ewerson don't use is as it is. just use your switch in the heightForRowAtIndexPath function and instead of cell.hidden, do a return 0.0

Comment: thanks for helping... @apikurious I tried, I used the following code: [link] http://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmzq.png  
but it did not work, he gave the following error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x7fff586eff8)

Comment: I got guys thank you @apikurious
i use this cod...

switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = "1."
    cell.valueLabel.text = array.item1
case 1:
    if array.item2 != "nil" {
        cell.fieldLabel.text = "2."
        cell.valueLabel.text = array.item2
        tableView.RowHeight = 80
    } else {
        cell.hidden = true
        tableView.rowHeight = 0
        break
default:
    cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
    cell.valueLabel.text = ""
}
}

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space, one way is to change the height return within heightForRowAtIndexPath.

But in heightForRowAtIndexPath we can not call cellForRowAtIndexPath as it will then become recursive and the application would crash. So we must use our Data Source to check which elements to return an empty height.

Like this:

```
class My_UITableView: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var My_Items: [Int: Strings] = [Int: String](); //this is your data source which contains your items.

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (My_Items.count > indexPath.row){
            if let Current_Item = My_Items[indexPath.row] {
                if (Current_Item == ""){
                    return 0; //whatever value you wish to check in your data source item, if it matches your condition send a different height.
                }
            }
        }
        return 50;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping... @Ghulam Ali I tried, I used the following code: [link] i.stack.imgur.com/RKmzq.png but it did not work, he gave the following error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x7fff586eff8)

Comment: This is because cellForRowAtIndexPath is calling heightForRowAtIndexPath recursively. You must check whether the text is nil from your data source and not from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: If you are still having problem, I have updated the answer to clarify it further.

Comment: OK. thank you for your time. But i having try any ways ... i give up this way. I will think about bringing that data otherwise. Just do not know how. Thanks you again

Comment: It's okay. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

In your `viewWillLayoutSubview` method of `ViewController` that contains the `tableView` change tableView separatorStyle to `UITableViewSeparatorStyle.None` .This will make the difference that you need, I think.